# How to grey out the background while spinner is running in React

Tags: css, reactjs

How to grey out the background application or screen while spinner is running in  React.
Everything is working fine but screen is not grey out in code

```
{
        loading ? <Spinner animation="border" variant="success"  />  : (<Modal></Modal>)
    }
```

my css part is

```
.spinner-border{
    width: 6rem !important;
    height: 6rem !important;
    left: 880px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose everything in a view and place the backgroundColor in rgba, if necessary, place the view with zindex -1

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)', alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
  <Spinner animation="border" variant="success" />
</View>
```

Comment: Hi @Ruan Duarte it throws error Attempted import error: 'View' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'.

Comment: Hi @Ruan Duarte i think view is part of react native not reactjs

Comment: You can use a div yourself and apply style = {{...}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `opacity` - you can't do it with a `backgroundColor` unless you position the whole `View` *over* your original `View` with `position: absolute` which will be difficult especially if your `View` is dynamic.

Just enclose everything in this and `spinning` will decide if you grey out or not:

React Native:

```
<View
  pointerEvents={spinning > 0 ? 'none' : 'auto'}
  style={{ flex: 1, opacity: spinning > 0 ? 0.25 : 1}}>

   <...usual components />
</View>
```

`pointerEvents` will disable all touch events

React.js:

```
<div
  style={{
     opacity: spinning > 0 ? 0.25 : 1,
     pointerEvents: spinning > 0 ? 'none' : 'auto'
  }}>

   <...usual components />
</div>
```